# Behaviour of getchar() in a while loop

Tags: c, getchar

I am running this c program in the terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int result = 0;

    while(result <= 0) 
    {
        int result = (getchar() != EOF);
        result = 2;
        printf("x");        
    }

    printf("out\n");
}
```

After that I type in the word "hello" followed by a return. The result is that I get multiple 'x' characters.

Why doesn't this terminate after the first 'x'?

Comment: Tip: a well enabled compiler may report "warning: variable 'result' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]".  Save time and enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're re-declaring (shadowing `result`) inside the while loop.  The `result` that is used in `while(result <= 0)` is the one that is declared outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks. A bit stupid, I was kind off blind for the obvious I guess.

Comment: so to address the wording of the question title directly - the mystery had nothing to do with getchar()

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int result = 0;  /* here *OUTER* result gets the value 0 */

    while(result <= 0) /* THIS MAKES THE While to execute forever */
    {
        int result = (getchar() != EOF);  /* THIS VARIABLE IS ***NOT*** THE outside result variable */
        result = 2; /* external block result is not visible here so this assign goes to the above inner result */
        printf("x");        
        /* INNER result CEASES TO EXIST HERE */
    }

    printf("out\n");
}
```

As you can deduct from the comments, the `result` variable that is compared in the `while` test is the outer one, while the inner one hides the outer one, no assignations can be made to it in the body of the loop, so the loop runs forever.  You get an infinite string of `x`s printed on `stdout`.